# parenthesis is not recognized

Tags: vba, excel

Anybody can please look at my code below in vba.

```
 wb2.ActiveSheet.Range("K" & lrow3 + 1).Value = "(" & wb2.ActiveSheet.Range("K" & lrow3 + 1).Value * -1 & ")"
```

This only outputs

```
-24.5
```

That formula will convert the value in a cell if the value of the cell is negative and put it inside the parenthesis. Thanks.

Comment: are you trying to have this formula set to this cell ?

Comment: @ShaiRado Yes, thats what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Why don't you just use a number format? Looks like you're trying to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @teylyn Opps, but the column is not constant. That's just my sample :) Thanks

Comment: The column "K" looks pretty constant to me. If you can identify the cell, then you can apply a number format.

Comment: @teylyn Number Format will only convert the data to positive or negative. What i want is if its a negative number, i will convert it to positive and and enclose the data with parenthesis.

Comment: Number formats will not convert anything. It is just formatting, i.e. display. The underlying value does not change. What you are trying to do with the macro will actually take a number and turn it into text. Unsuable for further calculations.

Comment: Have you done ANY research at all before asking your question? It seems you don't really understand how number formats work. And there are lots of resources about how to use number formats in VBA. You just couldn't be bothered to look, it seems.

Comment: @teylyn Yep that's what I mean .. Im sorrry, but I've tried every suggestions, I just can't make it work. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take this as a guide:

A negative value is copied into cell A2. A2 is then formatted to show negative values in brackets, with two decimals.

```
Sub test()
Range("A1").Copy Range("A2")
Range("A2").NumberFormat = "0.00;(0.00);0"

End Sub
```

[image]

Nothing gets converted. No brackets are concatenated. The cell is simply formatted with a custom number format. The syntax for number formats in Excel is

```
<format for positive values>;<format for negative values>;<format for zeroes>;text
```

for example, the custom format

```
0;-0;;
```

will show positive values as whole numbers, negative values with a leading `-` sign, hide zeroes and hide text.

Answer (score 1):

In vba code:

```
if wb2.ActiveSheet.Range("K" & lrow3 + 1).Value<=0 then
    wb2.ActiveSheet.Range("K" & lrow3 + 1).Value = wb2.ActiveSheet.Range("K" & lrow3 + 1).Value * -1
else
    wb2.ActiveSheet.Range("K" & lrow3 + 1).numberformat = "@"
    wb2.ActiveSheet.Range("K" & lrow3 + 1).Value = "(" & wb2.ActiveSheet.Range("K" & lrow3 + 1).Value * -1 & ")"
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

Select your Range, then go to *Format Cells*... --> *Custom*, and type in:

```
_(* #,##0_);_(* (#,##0);_("-");_()
```

This will take your negative values and pout it inside brackets

Comment: Is there's any way you can convert this to VBA?